# Nested colspan in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to having a simple table.I am able to do the first callsapn.
but second one is not working.
table is in the picture below.
[image]

Below is my html code that I tried:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">{{ __('Major Technology Adopted') }}</th>
            <th colspan="10" class="text-center">{{ __('No Of Farmers Adopted Technology:Since Inception To Date') }}</th>


        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
            <th colspan="4" class="text-center">{{ __('CIG') }}</th>
            <th colspan="4">{{ __('Non-CIG') }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

</table>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: when running the code snippet, it looks like it works

Comment: @FrédéricLang 'Total Farmer' went under 'Major Technology Adopted' column.it should be under 'CIG'

Comment: looks like it miss a <th><th/> tag, I made an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
            <th rowspan="3" class="text-center">{{ __('Major Technology Adopted') }}</th>
            <th colspan="10" class="text-center">{{ __('No Of Farmers Adopted Technology:Since Inception To Date') }}</th>


        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
            <th colspan="4" class="text-center">{{ __('CIG') }}</th>
            <th colspan="4">{{ __('Non-CIG') }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

</table>
```

you should change rowspan 2 to 3 in `Major Technology Adopted`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

    <thead>
        <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
            <th rowspan="2" class="text-center">{{ __('Major Technology Adopted') }}</th>
            <th colspan="10" class="text-center">{{ __('No Of Farmers Adopted Technology:Since Inception To Date') }}</th>


        </tr>
        <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
            <th colspan="4" class="text-center">{{ __('CIG') }}</th>
            <th colspan="4">{{ __('Non-CIG') }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
<th></th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will be informative to you**

```
<thead>
    <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
        <th rowspan="3" class="text-center">{{ __('Major Technology Adopted') }}</th>
        <th colspan="10" class="text-center">{{ __('No Of Farmers Adopted Technology:Since Inception To Date') }}</th>


    </tr>
    <tr class="bg-dark text-white" align="center">
        <th colspan="4" class="text-center">{{ __('CIG') }}</th>
        <th colspan="4">{{ __('Non-CIG') }}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Farmer') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Farmers') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Total Ethnic') }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">{{ __('Female Ethnic') }}</th>
    </tr>

</thead>

</table>
```